# How can I do that Submit Button Click not Active in CSS at Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Chrome (OS: Windows) clicked this css in webpages.

But Firefox (OS: CentOS7) is not clicked this css in webpages.

Where can I fixed it?

in CSS

```
#submit .btn.btn-primary:before{
        visibility: visible;
        content: 'SubmitClicked';
        line-height: 1.2em;
        background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,#65a637,#5b9532);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-color: #65a637;
        border: 1px solid #4d7e2a;
        border-bottom-color: #4d7e2a;
        border-top-color: #4d7e2a;
        color: #fff;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #69ac39;
        text-shadow: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 4px;
       }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Pls show your html code

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite understand what are you actually means in this question. but from the title i think maybe you can set the pointer event to none like this:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

it will disable the button as the pointer has no event and cannot click or what ever on that button. and it's supported in chrome and also firefox 4.6 and above. if you want to create some disabled effect on that button, you could play with the color or opacity of the button

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'padding' of buttons, It won't be move on firefox

```
.btn.btn-primary{
  padding: 0;
}
```